# If element begins with a number, don't select the ending number

Tags: regex

I'm trying to select text for `Dolby Digital` channels, abbreviated `DD`, `DDP`, `DD+`, etc.

The problem I have is if the element already starts with `5.1` or `5`, (decimal or int), I don't want it to select any numbers after it, because it could accidentally select numbers that are part of a different element.

https://regex101.com/r/MNq3Mw/2

---

Regex

```
\b\040?(\d[.]?\d?\040?)?(DDP|DD\+?\s?)([. ]?\040?\d[.]?\d?)?\b
```

I'm using `\040` as whitespace, but I'd rather use `\s`, but it's selecting multiple lines.

I've tried lookahead and lookbehinds with no success.

---

Want All Selected

```
DDP 5.1
DD+ 5.1
DD 5.1
DDP5.1
DD+5.1
DD5.1
```

Want All Selected

```
5.1 DDP 
5.1 DD+
5.1 DD
5.1DDP
5.1DD+
5.1DD
```

Don't want the `5.1` ending selected

```
5.1 DDP 5.1
5.1 DD+ 5.1
5.1 DD 5.1
5.1DDP5.1
5.1DD+5.1
5.1DD5.1
```

Don't want the ending single number `5` selected

```
5.1 DDP 5
5.1 DD+ 5
5.1 DD 5
5.1DDP5
5.1DD+5
5.1DD5
```

Comment: `\b(\d+(?:\.\d+)?\s?)?(DD(?:P|\+?))\s?(?(1)|([.\s]?\d+(?:\.\d+)?)?\b)`? See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/PGxWXz/2).

Comment: Kudos for your clear statement of a reasonably complex question, especially for including numerous examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an [alternation](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) matching either or the formats:

```
\b(?:DDP|DD\+?)\s?5\.1|5\.1\s?(?:DDP|DD\+?)
```

- `\b` Word boundary
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `DDP|DD\+?` Match either DPP or DD and optional `+`
- `)` Close group
- `\s?5\.1` Match opitonal whitespace char and `5.1`
- `|` Or
- `5\.1\s?` Match `5.1` and optional whitespace char
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `DDP|DD\+?` Match either DPP or DD and optional `+`
- `)` Close group

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/7p5SI4/1)

With decimal or int:

```
\b(?:DDP|DD\+?)\s?\d+(?:\.\d+)?|\d+(?:\.\d+)?\s?(?:DDP|DD\+?)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/d6ZMHg/1)

Comment: Both your solution and Wiktor's work great, I am just doing some more testing.